# Maven delete files phase validate except selected files

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want to keep only some files on validate phase in a maven project and the other files I need delete from the project. There is a way to delete any file with **/*.java except for selected files like `src/main/com/usa/Person.java`?

Comment: Sounds simply wrong to delete files from src/main/java during a build...

Comment: I will not need these files, I will only close with some

Comment: The build should not change anything in src/main/java.

Comment: What do you mean by `I will close with some`? Do you use a version control system? Just delete them and make a commit of it ?